# Numpy Import Error

Tags: python, numpy

I installed numpy 1.7.1 version but there was a problem when I import numpy.

The error message is

"ImportError: cannot import name datetime_data"

There is one website shows the code:

http://nullege.com/codes/search/numpy.core.multiarray.datetime_data

My python version is 2.7.

Does anyone meet this problem before ?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Provide some code, please...

Comment: I found the question that is I installed 2 version of numpy in my computer. I already uninstalled the older one.